# Stripping wp_link_pages?

Tags: wp-autop

I can't figure out for the life of me how to strip the following code of the `<p>` tag.  Even adding the remove code for wpautop in my functions won't do it.

```
<?php wp_link_pages('before=Pages'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a better look at the [arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) that this functions accepts:

```
wp_link_pages(array(
  'before' => 'Pages', 
  'after'  => '',
));
```